# Dynamically Generate Google Maps API Key?

Tags: google-maps, curl

I'm building an application that dynamically creates websites for people on my server which they can then point their domain to using easy tools based off of cpanel XMLAPI. The website they build includes e-commerce stuff and google maps and more.

Everything works pretty smoothly except for the fact that my very non-techie clients will have no idea how(or why) to apply for a google maps api key (even though there is a simple place for them to upload/change it in the admin for my site). Once they access their site through their domain name, they'll need their own key.

Is there a way to dynamically generate a key? Maybe through cURL? I'm not very experienced w communication btw diff sites but am willing to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Google Maps API v3, the current version of the API.  It does not require an API key.  Unless their sites will get a **lot** of traffic, that should solve the problem.  For more information on what consititutes "a **lot** of traffic", see http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#hightrafficsite.

Comment: As of June 22nd 2016 this is no longer true, an API key is now required. In theory it's just for new sites but I have noticed old sites requiring it as well.